# Heroku git push Django migration failure for DuplicateTable

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

**Background**

Migrating a Django app from Digital Ocean to Heroku.  I had problems migrating the data, so I used pg_dump to get the schema and the data of each table.  Then ran those scripts in heroku.  I loaded my website and I can see the new data coming through.

**Problem**

Now when I push new code with the Heroku CLI that auto runs the deployment, it fails for this reason:  `psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "django_content_type" already exists`

The commands I run are

```
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git push heroku master"
```

The `Procfile` has `release: python manage.py migrate` which runs the commands, which I thought about taking it out but when I have migrations to run in the future this will cause an issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This sent me down a rabbit hole this morning, and I figured it out.  I am going to leave the question up since I could not find a similar one.

The issue came down to migrations being out of sync locally and remotely.  Following the instructions for the top answer on this post cleared up the issue: [Django Heroku Error "Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598676/django-heroku-error-your-models-have-changes-that-are-not-yet-reflected-in-a-mi)